# If a beam of light follows the path $y(x)=y_0\sin(x/y_0)$, what is the index of refraction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction

An exam question that showed up while I was studying:

> A plane wave refracts and follows a ray given by the equation $y=y_0\sin(x/y_0)$ where $y_0$ is a constant. Find the refractive index $n(y)$ and plot it.

I believe I've made a mistake in my calculation.

The wave propagates in the $x$-direction. So we are told the trajectory -- that's simple enough. Let us divide the material into thin sheets of height $dy$. If we zoom in on the path enough, we can use Snell's law to approximate the difference in the angle (between the sheets.) We get that

$$ n(y)\sin(\theta)=n(y+dy)\sin(\theta + d\theta).$$

To be clear, $\theta$ is measured from the $y$-axis. (So $dx/dy=\tan(\theta)$.) We can expand to first order to get that

$$ n(y)\sin(\theta)=n(y)\sin(\theta) + n(y)\cos(\theta)d\theta + n'(y)\sin(\theta)dy $$ whereupon we get (using the chain-rule backwards)

$$-n(\theta)\cos(\theta)=\frac{dn}{d\theta}\sin(\theta)$$

where $n(y)$ has been written $n(\theta).$ (There is no difference.) Now we can separate variables. The equation

$$\frac{dn}{n}=-\frac{d\theta}{\tan(\theta)}$$
yields
$$n(\theta)=\frac{1}{\sin(\theta)}.$$

Now the issue is when I go through the trig identities, that is, replacing $\tan(\theta)$ with $dx/dy$, I get that

$$\tan(\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(y/y_0)^2}}$$ which implies $n(y)=y/y_0.$ I have no idea if this is the right behavior. There is no divergence in $n(y)$ like I imagined there would be and strangely it seems to flip the sign with $y$. But $n(y)$ can never be negative to I am at a loss here.

Edit: I believe the integral *should* be $$n(\theta)=\frac{1}{|\sin(\theta)|}$$ which takes care of the sign issue.

Comment: Hi Alec - it looks like you're just looking for someone to check your work, and haven't really identified a conceptual question that you want to ask. If you edit the question to do that, I'll be happy to reopen it.

Comment: @DavidZ I made a mistake in my original post, and correcting it lead to an actual question. So that is convenient. Do you mind reopening it please?

Comment: Sure, the new version is better enough.

Comment: For you interest: this is the approximate path of rays in graded index rod optics, which have roughly a parabolic refractive index profile, maximal in the centre,

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Interesting. So my answer is wrong then, I imagine. Since this is linear and minimal at the center.

Comment: I do indeed work out $|\sin\theta(x)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^2 + 1}} =\frac{A}{n(y(x))}$ where $A$ is a constant of integration. Now $\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right|_{x=0} = 1$ so $A = n(0)/\sqrt{2}$ and so $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \sqrt{\frac{2\,n(y)^2}{n(0)^2} -1}$. I then get $n(y) = n(0)\;\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y}{y_0}\right)^2}$, which does look like a GRIN lens profile.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Wow that's perfect. I thought I made a mistake. Everything is clear now, thanks.